# How can I manage Scheduled/Automated Actions and Views with Git in Odoo 11?

Tags: odoo, erp, odoo-11

I am using Odoo 11 Enterprise hosted in my own server.

At this point, Odoo instance I have has many Automated/Scheduled Actions as well as custom Views.

The Views are mostly for printed documents. For example:

- `report_purchasequotation_document`
- `report_saleorder_document`
- `report_purchaseorder_document`
- `report_invoice_document`

I tried to search for files related to the views and the actions but it seems that it is not inside the file system.

How can I manage Automated/Scheduled Actions and Views with Git?

Comment: How did you get the report extensions into your system? Did you just make the extensions in technical settings, like the automated actions? There won't be nothing stored as file, because odoo is data driven and everything made on client (except attachments) will be stored directly in database. Automated Actions will be saved in table base_automation.

Comment: Yes I understand that everything is saved in database. What I want is to manage every Odoo related codes like Actions and Views with Git.

Comment: What Actions and View code (XML) do you want to manage? Really everything or just your own extensions?

Comment: Everything. Every Actions and View Codes of all extensions.